# InvalidOperationException : Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object with Mono.Cecil

Tags: invalidoperationexception, mono.cecil

I am trying to generate a custom DLL based on an existing sattelite assembly.
I want the new DLL to contain some resources of my choosing.

Below is my code:

```
private void GenerateTargetAssembly()
{
    var sourceDll = @"d:\input.dll";
    var targetDll = @"d:\output.dll";

    AssemblyDefinition ad = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(sourceDll);
    ad.MainModule.Resources.Clear();

    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();            
    ResourceWriter rw = new ResourceWriter(stream);
    rw.AddResource("test", "val");
    rw.AddResource("test1","val1");
    rw.Generate();

    EmbeddedResource er = new EmbeddedResource("resName", 
                            ManifestResourceAttributes.Public, stream);

    ad.MainModule.Resources.Add(er);
    ad.Write(targetDll);
}
```

However, on **ad.Write(@"d:\test.dll")** line, I get the **operation is not valid due to the current state of the object** error. Exception type : **InvalidOperationException**

Could somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It was because of the version of the DLL, which was not the latest. I do not get the specific exception any longer. However, I cannot seem to write a resource to a certain stream. I had to write to a temporary file, then read from that file and write into the target assembly.
Does anyone have an example that works ?